# Using requests to post data to an html form

Tags: python, html, post, input, python-requests

I am looking to use python in order to post data to a website form.
the website is http://up-to-no-good.appspot.com
I know that I need to use post, but I do not know how to get it to actually post.
The sample input I would like to send (using the requests module) is:

```
map     : arena_lumberyard at: 0 x, 0 y, 0 z
```

`players : 21 (33 max)`

`# userid name                uniqueid            connected ping loss state`
`#     88 "gza"               STEAM_0:0:31273869  30:33       70    0 active`
`#     75 "MasterDovahBeard"  STEAM_0:1:41046299  46:08      120    0 active`
`#    101 "Gigs"              STEAM_0:0:17483483  04:40       78    0 active`

Answer (score 1):

Use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). This module automates web navigation, forms, buttons, etc..

Comment: Thank you so so much. I will post later if I can get it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example: [requests doc - POST request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

you need to create a dictionary with the key/value data and pass it to `requests.post()`

```py
POST_DATA = {'user_id': 88
            ,'name'   : "gza"
            # ...
            }
content = requests.post('http://example.com/', data=POST_DATA).content
```